# In a one to many relation, get all owner items with only one element in the many side

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, dql

I have an "one to many" relation between Home and Person.
One home have many persons.
With DQL, what should be the query to get all homes with just one person?
I know how to get all homes without persons, with the:

```
where home.persons IS EMPTY
```

collection expression, but not how to get what I'm looking for.

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Founded :)

DQL has a function SIZE for collections, that way, this is possible:

```
where SIZE(home.persons) = 1
```

Hope this help some of you